# How to fix HTTP Error 404.8 in IIS10? (hiddenSegment)

Tags: xml, iis, visual-studio-code, iis-10, segment

I'm currently working with IIS and Visual Studio Code, trying to establish a successful server connection with my web application. These are the steps I have followed:

1. Created a new connection in IIS. (connectionName: "website1.com", dir: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website1", type: "http", hostName: "website1.com", port: 80, ipAddress: "All unassigned")
2. Connection Created
3. Under Directory Browsing of the project I enabled: "Time", "Size", "Extension", "Date".
4. Under Request Filtering, I created a new hiddenSegment called "_website1".

The following file "web.config" is created in the directory of the project "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website1"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <add segment="_website1" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image: DEMO 1]

[image]

QUESTIONS:

- Why does the segment "_website1" is not visible in the webApp and why no file has been created?
- How do I display the default IIS webApp (the one with the blue background and different languages)?
- After that, how do I create a communication with IIS and Visual Studio Code? (Is the extension IIS Express useful in this case)?

Please if you have any information do let me know.

Comment: You'd better find a book to learn IIS from scratch. That will not only show why you misunderstood the concepts, but also show the right ways to do things. Too lengthy to teach bit by bit here. (Tip, what you observed is by design and what should happen. What you wanted is either wrong, or not very likely to be the right way to go.)

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for your answer? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

1. Hidden segment doesn't mean IIS will inject _website1 in your request URL. It just specify the URL segmenet collection that will be blocked. If your request URL contain the segement "_website1", IIS return 404.8 to block that request.
   The reason for 404.8 is web.config is a default hidden segmenet value in request filter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments/

2. The page with blue background and different languages is the Default index of IIS Default Web Site. You should be able to find it in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

   If you want to display it in your website, please copy iisstart.htm and iisstart.png into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website1.

3.Once you copy these file to website1, you should be able to view the page via http://website1.com/iistart.htm. Or you could enable default document and access the page via http://website1.com/

I'm afraid it is unavailbale to debug application with IIS in VS code, you could only use IIS express instead. So copy project to IIS site and run it directly should be the way to communicate with IIS.

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou Do you have more question with it? I am always happy to reply these questions.